# Проекты из разных Solution-ов, Nuget и hint path

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Дано:**
Есть 2 солюшна.

1. MVC приложение
2. Набор библиотек с бизнес-логикой

Для дебага мне приходится добавлять нужные проекты в один солюшн. Я просто добавляю нужные проекты с бизнес логикой из солюшна 2 в мой солюшн 1 с моим MVC приложением.

**Проблема:**
Проблема в hint path и packages. Дело в том что когда ты выкачиваешь Nuget Packages для проекта, то он кладет их в папку packages около солюшена в рамках которого ты это делал.

Когда я добавляю проект из солюшна 2 в солюшн 1, а потом обновляю/добавляю какие-то Nuget packages, то они скачиваются в папку packages для солюшна 1. В то время как проект из солюшна 2 имеет hint path типа "../packages...". То есть он смотрит на папку packages своего, 2-го, солюшна. Естественно приходится менять hint path чтобы они смотрели на папку packages не от 2 солюшна.

**Почему это проблема:**
Потому что check-in-ить такие hint path нельзя. И в случае, когда csproj файл изменился (добавились например какие-то файлы), то приходится чистишь csproj файл. Писать правильные hint path оставляя при этом другие изменения, check-in-ить, а потом возвращать нужные hint path.

**Вопрос:**
Как избежать этих танцев с hint path и при этом оставить возможность девелопить и билдить проект в рамках разных солюшнов?

**Уточнение:**
Каждая библиотека с бизнес-логикой лежит в нугете. И при обычном сцении работы я её подключаю как нугет. Без этих танцев с добавлением проекта к солюшну. НО. Когда возникает ситуация когда мне нужно изменить эту бизнес логику и сразу же её подебажить в рамках конкретного приложения, то тогда мне приходится уже брать исходники этого нугета и добавлять в солюшн с моим приложением. Но мой вопрос вовсе не про это.

Мой вопрос про то, что у этой библиотеки с бизнес-логикой, которую я добавляю в свой солюшн для дебага, есть зависимости на другие нугеты. И эти нугеты нужно заресторить чтобы всё скомпилить. Но проблема в том что рестор кладет все библиотеки в package папку около солюшна в рамках которого мы это делаем.

А проект с бизнес логикой, который я добавляю в свой солюшн, физически хранится в другом месте, и состоит в рамках другого солюшна. И hint path в csproj смотрят на папку packages для его солюшна, а не для того в который я его добавляю. Вот тут проблема.

Зачекинить я эти hint path'ы, которые изменены чтобы смотреть на папку packages другого солюшна, не могу. Потому что тогда билд сломается на билд сервере.

Да, я могу держать открытым солюшн в котором состоит нугет с бизнес логикой, чтобы там делать нугет-рестор. Но хочется избавиться от этого и работать в рамках одной студии.

Comment: Имеет смысл настроить nuget так, чтобы локальный репозиторий пакетов был снаружи каталога с проектами.

Comment: @VladD Я почти пришел к этому. Но это будет означать что для каждого солюшна нужно будет поправить nuget.config. Если я не найду более легкого решения, то придется сделать так :)

Comment: Ну так, это ж только один раз. И у вас ведь не так много их?

Comment: @VladD И тут я понял что это решение тоже не подойдёт. Потому что hint path должны остаться вида "../packages/...". Это требования билдсервера. А в случае с выделением общей папки для всех нугетов придется изменить все hint path.

Comment: Эээ, не дело билд-сервера указывать пути. Можно подправить билд-скрипты, чтобы он заткнулся.

Comment: @VladD Билд-сервер их и не указывает. Он на них смотрит. Ему нужно чтобы hint path был вида "../packages/...". То есть вёл на папку packages родного солюшна. Поменять это я пока не в состоянии по ряду причин. Поэтому ищу способ облегчить себе жизнь :)

Comment: Ну, я имел в виду «указывает» в смысле «дерзко осмеливается требовать для своего функционирования тот или иной вид `HintPath`». А почему нельзя это легко поменять?

Comment: Может, тогда перенести солюшены на более внешний уровень? И подправить пути к проектам. Пусть все солюшены лежат в одном каталоге верхнего уровня. Но тогда тоже будет `HintPath` вида `..\..\packages\<...>`.

Comment: @VladD У меня привелегий на конфигурироване билд-сервера нет :) Пытаемся обойти своими силами.

Comment: Тогда затребуйте от команды, занимающейся билд-сервером. Это их баг, пусть чинят. Объявите severity = high и пусть работают.

Answer (score 1):

Мы вынесли общий код в Nuget-пакеты. Используем TFS Online, где можно создать своё [хранилище пакетов](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/feeds/create-feed). Это хранилище подключается в Visual Studio к обоим проектам.

Всё, что нужно было узнали из [документации Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/overview).

Практические советы:

1. Для Nuget'ов завели отдельный репозиторий в TFS Online.
2. Все Nuget'ы держим в одном солюшене, хотя это не обязательно. Просто у нас над ними работает только она команда, а если будут разные, можно и разнести.
3. `nuget.exe` держим прямо в солюшене из пункта 2.
4. Используем самописный скрипт на PowerShell, чтобы увеличивать номер версии пакета перед сборкой и публиковать. Выглядит так:

   ```
   param($csproj, $version)

   if ($version -ne 'major' -and $version -ne 'minor' -and $version -ne 'revision') {
     Write-Host 'Usage: build-next-version <.csproj file> major|minor|revision'
     exit -1
   }

   $csprojPath = Resolve-Path $csproj |
                 Split-Path

   $assemblyInfo = Join-Path -Path $csprojPath -ChildPath "Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs"

   Write-Host "AssemblyInfo.cs: $assemblyInfo"

   $versionPattern = "AssemblyVersion\(""(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.0""\)"

   $assemblyInfoVersion = Select-String -Path $assemblyInfo -Pattern $versionPattern -List
   $matches = $assemblyInfoVersion.Matches

   if (-not $matches.Success) {
     Write-Host "Can't find [assembly: AssemblyVersion(""M.m.r.0"")]"
     exit -2
   }

   $major = [Convert]::ToInt32($matches.Groups[1], 10)
   $minor = [Convert]::ToInt32($matches.Groups[2], 10)
   $revision = [Convert]::ToInt32($matches.Groups[3], 10)

   Write-Host "Detected version: $major.$minor.$revision"

   if ($version -eq 'revision') {
     $revision++;
   }
   elseif ($version -eq 'minor') {
     $revision = 0;
     $minor++;
   }
   elseif ($version -eq 'major') {
     $revision = 0;
     $minor = 0;
     $major++;
   }

   $newVersion = "$major.$minor.$revision"
   Write-Host "New version: $newVersion"

   (Get-Content $assemblyInfo) |
     % { $_ -replace "(Assembly(File)?Version)\(""([^""]+)""\)", "`$1(""$newVersion.0"")" } |
     Set-Content $assemblyInfo

   $nugetPath = $csproj -replace '\.csproj$', ".$newVersion.nupkg"
   Write-Host "NuGet packet: $nugetPath"

   $nuget = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Join-Path -ChildPath NuGet\nuget.exe

   & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe' $csproj /p:Configuration=Release
   & $nuget pack $csproj  -Properties Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory $csprojPath
   & $nuget push $nugetPath -Source <Здесь вставить ULR хранилища, что-то вроде https://company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/ProjectName/nuget/v3/index.json> -ApiKey VSTS
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. У нас тоже есть своё Nuget хранилище. Паблиш в это хранилище происходит после check-in-а, непосредственно на build сервере. Но я не совсем понимаю как ваш подход решит мою проблему.

Comment: @RoulanD, выносите код общих проектов в нугеты, тогда за корректностью ссылок на другие нугеты следит Visual Studio. Тех ужасов, которые вы описываете, просто не будет, каждый солюшн будет следить за своими пакетами. В действительности, у вашего текущего подхода есть ещё одна проблема: при рефакторинге в одном из солюшенов вы рискуете получить неработающий код в другом. Так делать просто не надо, а надо выносить общий код в нугеты, это и есть правильное решение в данном случае.

Comment: Я видимо не совсем правильно сформулировал вопрос. Я написал уточнение в шапке вопроса. Это должно прояснить ситуацию. Спасибо за ваши комментарии.

Comment: Да, так стало понятнее. Мы в такой ситуации сидим в двух студиях.